# Tattoo barcodes: are they worth the hassle?

Tags: internal-consistency

In Warlords it is common in the belt and asteroid colonies to "hand out" barcodes to individuals for security and labor reasons. With a simple scan the station security or guild master can see the basic bio of this person, past work and incidents, which ship they came on, etc. They are deemed more humane than chips and only slightly invasive by society at large, but are only prevalent in the outer colonies.

I would need (in my mind) these bar codes to be able to remain the same physically, but the information accessed can be changed over time. As well as having some sort of machine doing the tattoo to confront forgeries.

Is it worth the effort to tattoo thousands of miners and ship crews or would something else be far more efficient? Also would the idea of tattoo barcodes even work?

Comment: you could have the tattoo as a bio-chip that when you get a job the employer scans you and the tattoo would then update your info (would just be easier to just use normal chips instead)  "only slightly invasive then chips" well some people are using chips today and its far more hidden then a big tattoo. not to mention it's ripe for abuse just rip the skin off a miner spray on skin and bam your inside a rival mining rig

Comment: @Creed Arcon I feel that a chip would be easier to hack  (if you could hack it) then tampering with a tattoo. Also you can cover up a tattoo a chip would always be active .

Comment: you could use both, the chip as a scan when they are at checkpoints, then if the guard is not convinced the bio locked tattoo (means only your DNA that makes the tat work). hold out your arm citizen beep its not john doe kill him. but if it just a normal tattoo i don't think is worth it

Comment: Seems like a couple of fake tattoos and an accomplice would create a hard-to-dispute set of false records, great alibi for criminal activity. And a great way to obfuscate the location of folks who don't want to be located...and bodies.

Comment: Is this for identification or authentication? Because a barcode is trivial to copy, so if you can use it to open a locked door, it's a really bad idea.

Comment: Barcodes were invented when reading DNA was sci-fi. It is like a horse carriage. Why would anyone with future space technology use it? Read the DNA with a laser. Or quantum radar. Or read brain patterns.

Comment: Side-question: what if a worker lost the tattoo due an incident or another kind of trauma? Is there any "plan B" in your universe to identify such orphaned person to restore the identity?

Comment: @Yury Schkatula well after being shown the way I think I'm transferring to chips. So they would receive a new one, but that could lead to a proper identity theft. Would make a cool story.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

> They are deemed more humane than chips

Do you know why the Nazis tattooed serial numbers into the arms of concentration camp prisoners? Because it marks them for life as something they deemed inferior, worthless, the enemy, outsiders. It is definitely **not humane** to mark someone as a laborer and cut them off from any chance to ever climb the social ladder.

If these barcodes are only used in the belt and asteroid colonies, tattooed people will probably face discrimination just because they wear a visible mark that distinguishes them from residents of planets and other colonies. Compare it to todays racism, where people are judged and discriminated because they have dark skin, slitted eyes or some other visible feature that has nothing to do with their personality or worth as a person.

Additional disadvantage: It's rather easy to exploit, alter and otherwise temper with tattoos. You can cut (parts of) the skin off, thicken barcode lines with your own tattoo machine or use laser removal methods. All you need for identity theft is a high resolution photograph of someone else's tattoo.

If you want something unique and identifying, choose a fingerprint or a truly quick DNA test or implant some chip into a bone of an infant.
A DNA test has to be coupled with a second identifier because identical twins have basically identical DNA.

Comment: *"identical twins have identical finger prints."* Identical twins don't have identical fingerprints. +1 though for the first paragraph - wish I could upvote multiple times just for that.

Comment: I wouldn't be the least bit surprised if the German government of the 1930s and 1940s would have used subdermal contactless chips if those had been available. (Remember that various groups were also required to wear other visible markings.) Alas, they weren't, so they used what *was* available and suitable for the purpose. (One can and probably should argue that the purpose was wrong, but if one believes that the purpose is good, then it comes down to solving the problem, and tattoos *did* solve the problem.)

Comment: "If you want something unique and identifying, choose a fingerprint" *almost unique. On the scale of thousands of workers that would still work well, but if you scale it up to billions or trillions then it might not hold up so well. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint#Errors

Comment: How did those prisoners live in the society after having liberated?

Comment: "*it marks them for life*".  Hardly.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tattoo_removal

Comment: @RonJohn The article you linked states: "A poll that was done 4 years prior [in 2008] reported that the most common reasons were "too young when I got the tattoo" (20%), "it's permanent" and "I'm marked for life" (19%), and "I just don't like it" (18%). Now think which of these reasons apply to survivors of concentration camps... Also this article about the [History of Tatto Remocal](https://thefinery.net/history-of-tattoo-removal/) states that " it’s only in the last ten years that laser treatments have really been refined."

Comment: @RonJohn Well, out of context sure, but given the timeframe this happened, it certainly was believed to be "marked for life" considering the original laser that could remove tattoos was created in 1960 and only much more recently Q-switched lasers have become commercially available in the early 1990s.

Comment: @YElm and GrumpyCrouton: tattoo removal has been around for a hell of a lot longer than lasers have. http://pasadenatattooremoval.com/picosecond-laser-tattoo-removal-versus-old-mechanical-methods/ Sure, it left scars, but that's easy to, if not cover, but mask/hide with clothes **or even larger/other scars**.  "That scar isn't from a concentration camp, it's from {make up an accident)."

Comment: @RonJohn I don't see any dates on those pages, but yeah, obviously removing your skin would have always been an option in those cases but for a lot of people it wouldn't have been possible to do because of several reasons like money, maybe even just finding a doctor that would do it, among other reasons that likely exist.

Comment: Initial argument in this reasoning is unrelated to the question. The people in the outer colonies of the story have decided they like barcodes better than chips. Also the OP makes no mention of the fact that these barcodes carry some kind of unavoidable stigma with them. Just because you beleive the process of putting a barcode on the skin is inhumane, does not mean the people in the story the OP described feel the same. Aslo, the context matters, this is a job, not prison. -1 EDIT: to Add, if people can live in the outer colonies in a sci fi setting, tattoo removal likely wont be an issue.

Comment: Nothing you say is incorrect but it doesn't necessarily apply to this case. The nazi tattoos were intended to **single people out**. In OP's case, the barcodes are as ubiquitous as hardhats on a construction site. If you're the only one who has to wear the hardhat because you're [insert discriminator], then it's just like the nazi tattoos. When everyone wears a hardhat, the hardhat is not a label of [insert discriminator]. In the right context, **not** having a tattoo could single you out more than having a tattoo would.

Comment: @RonJohn and then there's the age old practice of masking a tattoo with another one created on top of it.

Comment: @PierreCathé only one of those seems to actually be an issue with fingerprints themselves, though even that seems to have been an issue with the procedure used to identify them, one would hope that a race able to live in the asteroid belt would have higher resolution, and therefore more accurate matching technology.

Answer (score 33):

What you describe is a database with the entry key being the tattooed bar-code.

The main problem I see is that to scan an individual you would need to access open skin, which in space is generally cumbersome when one is wearing a space suit: imagine having to scan miners accessing the mine, they are already fully dressed, to uncover part of their body would require additional time which would be subtracted to operation.

It sounds much more practical to scan the iris and use it as access key.

Comment: I was thinking the barcodes would be used on board the ship, air locks right before entry, and space stations. Maybe their suits also have custone barcodes that work kinda like dog tags?

Comment: @CelestialDragonEmperor, swapping a suit is really easy.

Comment: @L.Dutch Suits could keep a record of being sealed/unsealed (they probably should anyway for maintenance purposes). If suit/ID swapping is a problem, they might even have an extra step in suiting up that can only happen in designated areas or with the right tool, like those old Apple case-opening doohickeys. That way if you swap suits, they'll be able to find out.

Comment: @Cadence, that adds additional complexity to the system. OP is looking for practicality.

Comment: *"swapping a [space] suit is really easy"* I recall reading on [space.se], but am not up to digging out that Q&A at the moment, that present-day space suits are individually tailored. With ordinary clothing, something being off by a few cm is no big deal; with a spacesuit, it can be crippling.

Comment: You can simply add a small piece of plexiglass or similar to the suit where the code is located, can scan through it. Or just use highly metallic / radioactive ink so it can be scanned with something that doesn't need visuals - possibilities are endless if you just want to

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, I agree with what you state for present spacesuits. However, I assume that in case of space colonies, like in the OP's scenario, they would become more of a mass product.

Comment: Also, cant the individual change the barcode? Not to anything, but as I understand both bar codes and QR codes basically send binary via black/white coloring. Now, one cannot arbitrarily change black to white, but white can always be changed later on..

Comment: @L.Dutch Depends on how advanced automated manufacturing is. With cheap enough robotics, you can go for a body-scan in the morning and come back in the afternoon for a custom-tailored (e.g. 3D-printed) suit.

Comment: For the space suit issue, just include a spot that is [transparent and rests against the barcode](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-scan-a-QR-code-behind-thick-transparent-glass). For the ethics issue, have *everyone* get one, and your status/banking information/medical history/etc are all accessible by your personally coded barcode, just on different software.

Comment: To make it plain:  the barcode should only be a unique identifier.  The actual information is in the database, where it can be updated as required.  Authenticating the identity between the database record and the person requires something hard to fake (photo in the database, biometrics, etc.)  Then the barcode need not (should not!) be alterable.  To improve security, see if you can arrange for identification to be valuable only to the bearer, like credit for work that can only be claimed in some other way.  Controlled access also requires another factor.

Comment: It may be that space suits are swappable, but you need to scan your own barcode to access one, and that code is displayed to be scanned. If the barcode is on a hand/arm, the suits may even have built-in scanners that scan after the suit is sealed, clear when it opens, and lock up if your barcode doesn't match the assigned user.

Answer (score 31):

Tattoos are not more humane and less invasive than chips, depending on how each thing is used. Tattoos will be very visible on you, specially if they have to be somewhere easily accessible for scanning. They can also trigger allergic reactions which will be a permanent hassle to whomever you've inked until you can get them surgically removed.

Chips are less likely to trigger allergies. They can be smaller than a grain of rice today, so they might be microscopic when we become a spacefaring civilization. They are not visible and will not take space that you could use to tattoo something else. If all the chip does is give out a constant string of bits - which is all you need to access a database - it will outdo tattoos regarding how invasive and how efficient it is.

A chip will also be much harder to tamper with - with a tattoo, all you need is some ink and a needle to make a machine think that Peasant Joe is Mr. Tycoon McRichie. With chips, you need the services of a very expensive hacker.

In the end, biometry beats both. In China you can pay for a meal by smiling at a camera. This is deemed more secure nowadays than using a credit card with a chip. Credit card chips can be cloned with equipment that is reasonably cheap in some black markets (compared with the costs of making or modifying tattoos), but in order to cheat real time movement-tracking facial recognition you need a series of facelifts to look like your mark, and that takes a serious amount of time, money and detachment from your own image. Add a IR layer and not even that will do - even identical twins don't have the same thermal features. And all the equipment you need is a slightly more sophisticated version of a 21st century Kinect or Playstation 4 camera.

Go with biometry. You can't go wrong with it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81012/discussion-on-answer-by-renan-tattoo-barcodes-is-it-worth-the-hassle).

Answer (score 12):

One very important aspect to consider: **Information security**.

When you tattoo a person for easy scanning, you are putting a machine readable number on them. **Anyone can read that number and replicate it as a sticker to impersonate that person.** This would work even at a distance, it suffices that the entire tattoo becomes visible to the attacker once.

Any biometric marker performs much better than a tattoo in this regard: The biometric marker generally can not be measured at a distance, and is generally much harder to fake without being obvious. Nevertheless, biometric markers can generally be spoofed in the same way as a tattoo. Think for example finger prints: Any person leaves their fingerprints everywhere, so it's easy for an attacker to covertly obtain the whole set of their targets fingerprints. After that it's a simple matter of creating a silicon cover for their own finger to fool any fingerprint sensor.

So, if you want *real* security, you must use chips. The difference is that a chip is an *active* component; it can perform cryptographic computations by itself. This allows the chip to

- Tell the scanner its identity, and to
- **actually prove to the scanner that it's really that chip,**
- **without disclosing the secret key that's used for that proof.**

If the chip is built well, it cannot be copied without really, really expensive equipment, destroying the original in the process. As such, the greatest danger of using chips is, that someone's chip is taken away by force to be used by the attacker. Think: Kill the guards, cut out their chips, and enter whatever they were guarding. Impersonation is not impossible, but it becomes damn hard to cover up.

Comment: it would also be fairly easy for a person to change their tattoo and therfore disappear from the system

Answer (score 6):

In the world of pets both tattoos and chips are already widely used as a means of marking animals so that if it is somehow lost to the owner it can be recognised and brought back.

Just to make it very clear - whatever method is used it contains merely an identifier that is linked to a database entries. Any solution where the agent (tattoo or chip) should contain also the data requiring updates is prone to too many errors and problems.

As far as I can see the general direction is to use chips rather than tattoos. And there are few good reasons for that:

1. Implanting a chip is far easier, less invasive and time consuming than putting a tattoo. I guess everyone knows these days how much trouble it is to make even a simple tattoo. Implanting a chip is a single simple injection with a chip itself being a bit larger than a single [rice grain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microchip_implant_(animal)#/media/File:Microchip_rfid_rice.jpg). Also making a tattoo is rather painful. Again, implantation is simply an injection.
2. The chip lasts longer. Since it is using an RFID technology it does not require any power (the power is induced from a scanner to send back a signal). There is hardly anything that can break or fail. If it works it'll work for years and years. And it will always produce the same return signal. The tattoo is exposed to all the risk the skin is. It fades over time, gets blurry as the ink dissolves to some level, might become unreadable due to scars, burns etc. As a result it might even produce a different value than it had initially. Of course you might do a correction to a tattoo or even make a new one if the old is entirely unreadable but that brings us back to point one ;-)
3. Skin imperfections might make it difficult to effectively place a tattoo in a specific skin location. If you have a scar you can cover it with a tattoo of course but it won't be a precise one with sharp lines (as needed for bar codes). Similarly mole might cause it impossible to blacken a specific spot. I believe you should try using the same place for the identification tattoos to avoid multiple identities of a single person. A chip might be prone to similar problems (sometimes - but rarely it can actually even shift its position) but it's far easier to scan entire body with a proper scanner than to scan entire skin.
4. Chip resides under a skin, thus is invisible so it's less obvious. Of course it can work both as a benefit and a drawback depending on the goal to be achieved. But still if we're considering more humane option, I would consider something invisible better here.

Note, I'm not referring to artificial identification versus biometrics here as that is not what the OP has asked for. I'm also referring to the currently existing technology.

And guess what, not only the technology is in place, it has also already been enabled to people who wants to use it and are lucky enough (?) to have it within their range. Some [reading](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/business/news/us-tech-company-microchip-employees-first-three-square-market-wisconsin-a7856971.html) to find out more.

BTW, all my pets have chips implanted ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you're in a space-scenario, there's a good chance people have chips anyway - after all, it's the most reliably way to enable interfaces which react on your thoughts.

Depending on the situation, a barcode is heavily unreliable. Its main problem is that a barcode merely represents a bit of data - it's basically a number in a format that is easy to read for machines. 
And just like any other data, you can copy it. Increasing the amount of data (i.e. making the tattoo more complex) is a failed idea as well. You can't just arbitrarily increase complexity, or else the tattoo will change over time.

So, a barcode alone isn't all that useful. Combining it with retina scans or the like doesn't make sense either, as the barcode would be the weakest link, and therefore be negligible.

If you still want to pull through with this idea, I would advise to make the ink nanobots: The tattoo would become a computer, capable of cryptographically save interaction, but also have a failback-mechanism for cases when no higher technology is available (or needed).

Comment: I like this answer. I should add that it's quite a common concept in fiction to have interactive/context-sensitive tattoos. Examples include the magic ones in harry potter used by the Death Eaters, I remember many other examples, but can't name them off the top of my head. Generally the theme is that you can make them visible or hide them either at will or by pressing on them. Smart Tattoos are actually already something being developed as well. Harvard are making a smart-tattoo to monitor the blood-sugar of Diabetics for example.

Answer (score 2):

Tattoos might be ideal:

- They **need not be completely legible visually**, making them hard to copy without the wearers consent. Checksums or additional information may be incorporated in magnetic features of the ink (easily checkable by contact, impossible even at a slight distance), chemical composition of the ink may hold information and is esily checkable by Raman laser spectroscopy, inks of different colors can be set in close proximity, so only microscopic inspection will reveal there is more than one (mix) color. Multiple tattoos have to be pointed out by the wearer to make sense of more private information. By making the application process more technical, the bar is higher for the inevitable forgers.
- **They are on the outside, making them much easier to be checked for manipulations**. Anything implanted will communicate on radio or light frequencies without the communication partner in direct contact - this is ideal for man-in-the-middle attacks or spoofing by having powerful hardware in the background that can outcompute the partner. Touch-only reading of a tattoo with additional security features ensures that the read person will be aware of the reading, and the reader will be sure that the thing she is trying to read is actually the one doing the talking.
- **They can transport a tidy amount of information**. Think QR-codes.This would come in handy in scenarios where databases are prone to error, forgery and viruses. The tattoo **is** the document, not just a database key. The data may also be centrally stored somewhere, but the primary document is right there. Just like paper money can be forged today, this will inevitably lead to some people polishing their CV by adding entries, but if the positioning of the tattoo is also information, this will be very tricky ("So, Mr. Anderson, you are saying that between your stint in McDo in 2456 (elbow) and your present application in 2458 (lower biceps) you served in the Space Force, were VP of PR at PwC and built a company, all the while suffering a burn on that prison shaped spot on your forehead?"). **Blockchain!** (well ok, that's not how that works... but it's a chain of sorts!) Detected forgeries are highlighted, and a forger-spot (one unlikely to suffer large scale damage, like the white of the eyes) is populated with the details of the crime.
- **They can be made very resistant to theft**. While the close-proximity stipulations are all well and good for the normal minded forgers, more bloody minded criminals may be open to removing interesting tattoos wholesale, for later analysis. While this largely the same predicament that chip-wearers face, some of the same precautions can be taken: Materials that are dependent on good oxygenation (now the robbers need a medreactor to put the skin in), Steganography (which of these is his Club-card?), and others.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're mining asteroids, I'm assuming we're talking a society that's at least 100 years ahead of us.  In that case, **bar codes are fairly pointless**.

Facial recognition today is good enough to work for many consumer grade applications.  In 100+ years, it will be flawless.  And there certainly will be better biometric methods that come along.  Perhaps instant, remote DNA analysis.  Bar codes on people in this situation bring very little to the table.

Bar codes might still be useful for tracking equipment, but they will be a decidedly old school method of doing so.

Comment: facial recognition is the direction, in the future maybe body / iris / brainwave scan? or else: tattoo and barcodes and any method used to mark somebody is just non practical anymore (tg)